# Symfony 3 Form Entity type

Tags: php, forms, class, symfony, entity

I have a form class as a (service) and I use `entity type` for select an article.

In Symfony 2 this works:

```
$builder
    ->add('article', EntityType::class,
        array(
        'em' => $this->em,
        'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Article',
            'query_builder' => function ($em) {
                return $em->createQueryBuilder('a')
                ->where('a.active = 1');
            },
        'choice_label' => 'name')
    )
```

But in Symfony3 I got error:
`Neither the property "article" nor one of the methods ...`

My problem is that Article hasn't property `article`. When I rename article to name

```
->add('name', ...`
```

How can I pass Article Entity to Form please?

Comment: Show us you Entity connected to that form.

Comment: What is the data you expect to populate with that field ? (the result of `$form->getData()`)

Answer (score 2):

In Symfony 3, you need to use **Fully Qualified Class Name**, so instead of:

```
'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Article',
```

you need to use:

```
'class' => \MyBundle\Entity\Article::class,
```

Read more about this in the book: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#building-the-form
And maybe you want to check all other things that you need to change when upgrading from Symfony 2 to Symfony 3: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md